# Make one section of the webpage responsive by different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My web page is simply consisted of 3 sections:

1:section 1, on the left, it is responsible for displaying messages, it is a small area and is "aligned" to the left of the screen.

2:section 2, on the right, it is another area and is "aligned" to the right of the screen.

3:section 3, on the middle, it is the "main" area of the page and it is consisted of quite a few number of elements that "fixed" with the screen by many `div` tag. I really think I over use the `div` here.

I have already made the section 3 look organized by manually fixed (define absolute position and pixel) those `div`. But it only look good in my computer with one screen size. I want to make it responsive to other devices by using `mediaQuery`. But since I got so many `div` it will be a pain to specifies the position for each. **Can I wrapp the whole section 3 with another div wrapper and then just change this wrapper position?** I tried but I failed.

Or is there another efficient way? I am open for bootstrap but I can not find any framework similar to my design. And My design is really simple so get it done without a template would be the best.

Section 3 looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jpdw4f7/

Comment: I highly suggest you look into bootstrap instead of creating your own css for responsive design, its way easier to get a bootstrap design and then modify it according to your need than building your own from scratch.

Comment: you must not use inline style to make responsive, Please use internal style or external css file. In your jsfiddle, you are using position, top, left to align element...which is not a proper way. 
try this...
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp